# art_sigsegv_fault when entering JNI function in C code within android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm using Kotlin and JNI as I'm looking to port a C program to Android and I'm wondering why I'm currently getting an "art_sigsegv_fault" as soon as the JNI function's breakpoint is hit.

Kotlin code:

```
import com.root.Main

class SettingsScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val MainC = Main()

    fun startButton(view: View)
        MainC.callMainFromJNI("test")
    }
}
```

MainC.c

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_root_hping2_Main_callMainFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject pThis, jstring argument){

    printf("Size of char: %ld byte\n",sizeof(char));
    return;
}
```

Breakpoint is on the printf , however, when I go to debug, I get the "art_sigsegv_fault" error and I'm not able to see any of the values of the parameters. This is within Android Studio

**EDIT:**
When i remove the jstring argument and don't pass the string into the function, it works correctly. What would the reason for this be?

Comment: Unable to reproduce (using the emulator). Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only it's from Java, not Kotlin, and the JNI file is straight C, not C++.  If I take the jstring argument out of everything, it works, and the debugger lets me single-step through the JNI code, with a successful return.  But if I add the jstring argument back in, and adjust the class declaration to provide a string as an argument, I get the same crash with a "art_sigsegv_fault" reported.  The function takes an earlier jint argument, which is what worked without the second jstring argument.  Seems clearly related to the added jstring argument, though it might not.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is within: [Different behavior of Native C++ Android projects when using Java and Kotlin as a base language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523444/different-behavior-of-native-c-android-projects-when-using-java-and-kotlin-as)

It looks to be a bug regarding the API Emulator and which version is being used. If the version is downgraded to API 25, no issues. As well, if the application is built on a device rather than an emulator will help with this issue.